# Is there a need for corrigendum in this case?

Tags: publications

After publication of my paper, I have discovered that I made a typo citing a very well known formula (part of undergraduate curriculum). Is there a need for corrigendum, as it is a well known formula ?

thanks

Comment: I routinely cite undergraduate textbooks. It is sometimes important to reference basic materials to those who are not completely familiar with the topic.

Comment: If you mean that it is only the citation that's wrong, not the formula itself: no, this is not worth a corrigendum.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify your field, but in engineering and physics typos in formulae are fairly common (I daresay that papers without typos are the exception rather than the rule), and, no, there's really no need to write a corrigendum, especially if the formula is well known (everyone will understand that it's a typo).

Of course, in the above I assumed that what you derived in the rest of the paper was derived with the right formula.

Answer (score 1):

A corrigendum where?  To publish it is (as the others say) not needed.   To put it on your web site along with the listing of all your papers, fine.